# Full Swivel TV Mount on Vertical Studs

Tags: television, mount

I am trying to mount our new 60 inch TV onto a wall.  The studs behind the drywall in the particular area are horizontal and there is too much space in between to mount into the studs.  I cut 2x8s and secured them into the studs vertically in front of the drywall. Will this be okay to hold the weight of the TV (50lbs) and the full motion swivel mount (20lbs)?

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: studs are never horizontal. You have some other interesting framing going behind there. What kind of wall is this (interior? Exterior?)

Comment: Sounds like you may have some kind of strapping, or maybe a sound attenuation channel you've attached to, but not the stud. Otherwise, what's holding your ceiling up?

Comment: Yeah I think maybe you have the words "vertically" and "horizontally" swapped. If you can hang off the 2x8 then so can your TV.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I wish I could send a picture of the area.  The wall is interior.  There are two studs going up vertically and then studs (I found them with a stud finder and felt the wood behind the drywall when my electrican put to do some wiring).  That is the horizontal part I was talking about

Comment: There may be horizontal fire or brace blocking that you're confusing for studs. In any case, your original plan is fine (if a bit unsightly). It doesn't take much to hang 50 lbs. on a wall, and that would certainly do it. 3" construction screws (gold "drywall" type screws) would be fine at 2 per contact point. Lag screws are overkill here.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like maybe there used to be a window where you're putting the TV, is that possible?  That would explain the framing you're hitting.

Anyway - it sounds like you put 2x8s from the top of what used to be the window to the bottom.  This will be more than enough support, as long as the 2x8s were attached with big screws, lag screws, lumber screws, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The better option would be to cut the 2x8, and secure it to the vertical studs.  A couple lag screws into each stud, and the 2x8 should be a permanent fixture. Some folks prefer to use plywood for this, instead of 2x lumber.

Since you don't know what the purpose of the horizontal members, or how they're attached to the studs. It's better not to use them to support anything.

Make sure to drill pilot holes through the 2x8, and put the screws in the center of the studs edge. This will prevent the wood from splitting, and give you the best hold.  Cutting the board a bit longer than needed, will reduce the chances of the board splitting.

You'll also want to use some fairly large washers on the lag screws, so they spread the load against the 2x8s face. This will prevent the screw heads from digging into the wood too much.

Comment: Also:  if you're mounting the 2x8's on the wall surface and affixing them on to the studs edge with lags it would be wise to cut the length an inch or more longer so as not to have the lags at the very edge of the 2x8? To avoid potential splitting?

Comment: Hi Everyone, thanks for the comments!  I think I'll go the route I already took and maybe have my contractor take a look at it.